# How can I restore the scripts/addons folder after accidentally deleting it?

Tags: add-on, installation

I accidentally deleted the scripts/addons folder. I don't want to reinstall Blender as I don't want to mess up the installation. Is there a way to just download the add ons? I'm using Blender 2.83 and I'm on a Mac.

Comment: From the repo https://github.com/blender/blender-addons  (and addons-contrib)

Comment: You messed up the installation already, so reinstalling should not be the issue. Just keep your startup.blend and user prefs.blend.

Answer (score 2):

Download the Windows Portable .Zip package from the Blender website (instead of the installer). Open the Zip file and extract just the missing folder. The files are all scripts/add-ons so it *should* be the same for all versions (so shouldn't be a problem for Mac).